# javascript, put labels in hashmap to conver in json format

Tags: javascript, json, hashmap

I have a hashmap like this:

```
mapUltimos2Anhos: {"La Coruña":11,"Pamplona":2,"León":9,"Valencia":4,"Las Palmas de Gran Canaria":3,"Oviedo":3,"Salamanca":2,"Albacete":3}
```

But I need convert this code in another JSON format to use in Google Geochart; the code should be:

```
[{"Ciudad": "La Coruña", "Clientes":11}, {"Ciudad":"Pamplona", "Clientes:2}, ...]
```

How I can convert the first format in the second????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cycle through your object using a [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, then push objects to an array using it's keys and values:

```js
var hash =  {"La Coruña":11,"Pamplona":2,"León":9,"Valencia":4,"Las Palmas de Gran Canaria":3,"Oviedo":3,"Salamanca":2,"Albacete":3}
var arr = [];
    
for (var prop in hash) {
  arr.push({'Ciudad': prop,'Clientes': hash[prop]});
}
    
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Great!, it works passing de data, (your var hash), like a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could get all keys of the object and then iterate over and return an array with new objects.

```js
var object = { mapUltimos2Anhos: { "La Coruña": 11, "Pamplona": 2, "León": 9, "Valencia": 4, "Las Palmas de Gran Canaria": 3, "Oviedo": 3, "Salamanca": 2, "Albacete": 3 } },
    result = Object.keys(object.mapUltimos2Anhos).map(function (k) {
        return { "Ciudad": k, "Clientes": object.mapUltimos2Anhos[k] };
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have to pass the data like a parameter, for that the Spencer`s answer is better for me.